# Установка pip для python3.7

Tags: python, pip

У меня стоит Python 2.7.12, Python 3.5.2 и Python 3.7.6. Вопрос! Как в этом случае установить pip для 3.7 версии не удаляя 3.5? Система Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia.

Comment: У меня стоят два питона (системный маковский 2.7 и поставленный 3.7), но 3 версии — это уже слегка перебор...

Comment: Какой командой вы открываете интерпретатор 3.5?

Comment: 3.5 - python3, 3.7 - python3.7

Comment: `python3 -m pip install <module>` — pip 3.5. `python3.7 -m pip install module` — pip 3.7.

Comment: Примите ответ, если он вам помог: галочка слева от ответа.

Comment: Проблема в том, что при создании виртуального окружения через venv, pip не переносится в него.

Comment: PyCharm????????

Comment: PyCharm-ом не пользуюсь.

Comment: Тогда рекомендую воспользоваться. Он решает эту проблему.

Answer (score 0):

`python3 -m pip install <module>` — pip 3.5.

`python3.7 -m pip install <module>` — pip 3.7.